# how to optimal cp function in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, copy

I made a bash script in which there is a copy function.
This bash script will be run for 1-4gb files.
like this approximately

```
dirB="/home/bsd"
dirC="/home/asd"
funcCP(){
    asd=$(find $dirB -regexype posix-egrep -iregex"^.*/XXX_[0-9]{3}\.txt$")
    for var in $asd
    do
        if var = xxx
        then
            cp -rp $var $dirC
        else
            echo "error"
        fi
    done
}
funcCP
```

Today I just realized that this bash script is nt running optimally. The file that I copied was 4gb in size. But in the destination directory, the copy results are sometimes not completely 4gb, can be only 1gb, sometimes 2gb.

I tried the script outside the bash file (manually), and the results are perfect! The file is copied to the destination directory with no size difference.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Make sure to log the size of the file and output of cp, in case the file wasn't 4gb at the time it was copied, it if the target ran out of space

Comment: based on your question, I assume that the destination file is smaller than the source file.  Even though they are different sizes they may have the same content.  Can you diff the source and tarrget and see iif they are the same?  Or use an md5sum program on them to get the content hash, etc.  By way of explanation,  the copy may have defragged an internally fragmented file or you may be copying to a different file system ( different block size ) - clearly just guessing.  Anyway, compare the files by some means other than size.

Comment: @thatotherguy destination ha a big space..thanks bro

Comment: @Mark oke.. i ll try to check. thanks bro..

Comment: @DigvijayS i ll edit the question..  thanks bro

Comment: @TsabitAbdullah The code in your latest edit will not work at all due to typos and syntax errors. Please edit with the *exact* code you're using. I'd recommend running your code through [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) and fixing the problems it points out -- well, except it's going to tell you your way of looping over files is all wrong, so see [BashFAQ #20](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020) for better methods. Also, is this a single file that's being copied and coming out the wrong size, or the entire directory?